# How do I start a C++ thread at program startup?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm writing a C++ library to allow programs to talk to a service in the cloud. I want to run a background thread which periodically checks the server and restarts it in case of failure. However it would be nice for the main program outside the library not to have to worry about starting the thread. The use of library should be limited to `useProcess()`. By this point the thread should already be running.

**How do I start a thread without the main program having to call any functions?** Is there a way to do this in a static constructor of my service class so that it starts the thread at program start (as I would do in Java)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it precisely that way -- you can have a global object whose constructor starts the thread at program start.

Personally, I think having a library start up a thread unexpectedly is not a good idea, but it's possible that it makes sense in your use case. Make sure to document the thread's precise requirements, how to shut it down, and so on. All the threads in a process *must* cooperate.

Example code:

```
#include <cstdio>

//--------- BEGIN LIBRARY
class MyThread
{ // The real code goes here
public:
    MyThread()
    { printf("A MyThread has been constructed\n"); }
    ~MyThread()
    { printf("A MyThread has been destroyed\n"); }
    void Start()
    { printf("A MyThread has been started\n"); }
    void Stop()
    { printf("A MyThread has been stopped\n"); }
};

class MyThreadCreator
{ // Just a helper class to construct/start/stop/destroy the other
public:
    MyThread thread;
    MyThreadCreator() { thread.Start(); }
    ~MyThreadCreator() { thread.Stop(); }
};
MyThreadCreator p;
//---------- END LIBRARY

int main()
{
    printf("Main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

> A MyThread has been constructed
>   A MyThread has been started
>   Main
>   A MyThread has been stopped
>   A MyThread has been destroyed

Comment: what would you recommend instead?

Comment: also could I get a quick example please?

Comment: @Drgabble I would recommend having functions that start and stop the thread that those using your library can call.

Comment: "Personally, I think having a library start up a thread unexpectedly is not a good idea".... Have you ever seen how many threads the C(++) standard libraries start at program start?

Comment: @Drgabble I think an important feature of a library is that `int main() { return 0; }` does not abort. If you have a thread start by a global constructor, you still have to `join()` or `detach()` it before it destructs.

Comment: As an aside, starting threads during static initialization is problematic. The order of initialization of global static init variables is not defined. Let's say you have a static logger object and a static-init thread created that wants to log something... Is the logger init yet? Also, static initialization is performed by a single thread. You are introducing opportunity for races and difficult to find defects by creating a thread during static init. Consider a library bookends pattern: LibInit() and LibDeinit(). (as suggested by @DavidSchwartz)

Comment: What @DavidThomas said, though I'd clarify that the order is only undefined when comparing objects from different translation units; within a single TU, the order is precisely that of declaration. As for the code, I'm not sure why you made 2 classes here. What does the 2nd one actually add? And if the (real) class doesn't need to be `extern`ed, then I'd declare it `static`, but that's minor.

Comment: @underscore_d Agreed.  precisely that of **_definition_**. Taking specializations into account.

Comment: @DavidThomas Indeed, of _**definition**_! [kicks self] I know this, having done some very careful definition-ordering lately... but guess I lapsed into thinking about class members following declaration. Thanks for correcting.